# How to select element with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to select this element with puppeteer: [image: Text], using this code:

```
        const items =  document.querySelectorAll(".s-item")

    for (const item of  items) {
        list.push(
            {
                title: item.querySelector(".s-item__title").innerText.includes('2/102'),    
                price:   item.querySelector(".s-item__price").innerText.replace('$', ''),
                date: item.querySelector(".s-item__title--tagblock").innerText.replace("o", "")
            }
        )
    }
```

However, I get back an error message saying "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'replace')" From the "date" property.

Comment: please shed some light, what is `items`?

Comment: also, from the inspector screenshot, I see `.s-item__title--tag` and `.s-item__title--tagblock`, but I can't see `.s-item__title`

Comment: Sorry my bad, just edited the post.

Comment: `item.querySelector(".POSITIVE").replace("o", "")` should be `item.querySelector(".POSITIVE").innerText.replace("o", "")`

Comment: also, as Shajith Kunnumbrath noted in the answer below, the `.POSITIVE` element is not always present (some products don't have it), so you should check if it exists before trying to access the `innerText` property

Comment: I did that it now says "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerText')"

Comment: please check Shajith Kunnumbrath answer

Comment: Answered in [Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent') in Puppeteer evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72522839/cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-textcontent-in-puppeteer-evaluate/72534230#72534230).

Answer (score 0):

You can do a null check before applying replace string method to DOM select statement : item.querySelector(".POSITIVE")

ie:
date: item.querySelector(".POSITIVE")? item.querySelector(".POSITIVE").replace("o", ""):""

Comment: `item.querySelector(".POSITIVE")`  + `.innerText` + etc.

Comment: @GrafiCode Right!!

Comment: I did as you advised and added a null check , and now it always returns as null. I also added a waitfor function in order to wait for the element to load. It doesn't. It is as if the element doesn't exist

Comment: You can add your code inside the DOMContentLoaded event listener to in order to wait for DOM element loaded instead of adding the timer `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    //your code goes here
});`