# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent') in Puppeteer evaluate

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to use Puppeteer to scrape this element from eBay:

[image]

However, when I run my code, I get an error that says "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')". This is my code:

```js
async function scrape() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=Blastoise+%282%2F102%29+%5BCelebrations%3A+Classic+Collection%5D&_sacat=0&Graded=No&_dcat=183454&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1');

  await page.waitForSelector('.s-item');

  let cards = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let cardElement = document.body.querySelectorAll('.s-item')
    let cards = Object.values(cardElement).map(x => {
      return {
        date: x.querySelector('.s-item__title--tagblock span.POSITIVE').textContent ? ? null
      }
    })

    return cards
  })

  console.log(cards)
})()
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Maybe something adds the `POSITIVE` class dynamically, and it's not there when your script runs.

Comment: Reminder from the [ebay TOS](https://www.ebay.com/help/policies/member-behaviour-policies/user-agreement?id=4259#3) _you will not: use any robot, spider, scraper, data mining tools, data gathering and extraction tools, or other automated means to access our Services for any purpose, except with the prior express permission of eBay;_

Comment: No problem.  Use [the API](https://developer.ebay.com/develop/apis) instead:

Answer (score 0):

The first item in the result list is sort of a dummy/template/placeholder node that has no data in it. You can use `.slice(1)` or `.s-item:not(:first-child)` to skip that first node.

While you're at it, you might as well make your `waitForSelector` more precise to match the element you're about to select (although this line isn't necessary, as I'll explain below), use `domcontentloaded` to speed up `goto` and use `?.textContent` so you can see undefined rather than a crash, which is how I debugged the problem. `.textContent ?? null` doesn't work because the throw happens before `?? null` has the chance to evaluate.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^14.1.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=Blastoise+%282%2F102%29+%5BCelebrations%3A+Classic+Collection%5D&_sacat=0&Graded=No&_dcat=183454&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1";
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  await page.waitForSelector(".s-item .s-item__title--tagblock span.POSITIVE");
  const cards = await page.evaluate(() =>
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".s-item:not(:first-child)")].map(x => ({
      date: x
        .querySelector(".s-item__title--tagblock span.POSITIVE")
        ?.textContent
    }))
  );
  console.log(cards);
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Better yet, skip Puppeteer entirely and make an HTTP request with Axios or fetch, then use Cheerio to parse the static HTML, which already has the data you need:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

const url = "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=Blastoise+%282%2F102%29+%5BCelebrations%3A+Classic+Collection%5D&_sacat=0&Graded=No&_dcat=183454&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1";
axios.get(url).then(({data}) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);
  const cards = [];
  $(".s-item:not(:first-child)").each(function (i, e) {
    $(this).find(".s-item__title--tagblock .POSITIVE").each(function (i, e) {
      cards.push($(this).text().trim());
    });
  });
  console.log(cards);
})
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ggorlen's answer, for your purpose you can use an NPM package [`ecommerce-scraper-js`](https://github.com/dimitryzub/ecommerce-scraper-js). It allows you to get an eBay listing with this simple code:

```js
import { ebay } from "ecommerce-scraper-js";

ebay.getListings("Blastoise (2/102) [Celebrations: Classic Collection]").then(console.log);
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
      "sponsored":true,
      "title":"Blastoise 2/102 HOLO Celebrations Classic Collection Pokemon 25th Anniversary NM",
      "link":"https://www.ebay.com/itm/175146532246?hash=item28c78bfd96:g:q8AAAOSwJUhiC2jb&amdata=enc%3AAQAIAAABAAzeUuF9yss1SxDS%2BLWVndBRNaJ6arl%2BxER%2Bh4x8uVo6KufFiL%2B9hjNHWM9FVvdbtlih2IAbqVE0kyERcGVQ85Lh6DRc27740D7WjaXSzN54htMYHgPmcg2ZSJMJ7gOAShTn6pls%2BmxV2%2Bk1QHDbcBczdG%2FM99R2U9osp0TyqnjNI6AXX5DACK6XC0zKx1gY%2BPC08iOdr0MJ9M%2BB3PQRhUes0FVSQHpEGT2V7vmWgbCJxbOoHj8YQUUB6VBsB0boYX3C0WWXShh8SLq7nCbDGfc039tXeqr3LXe7YLMJpJiqbm%2FWCWHIXdtyX1%2F%2FK7961ZGYXQ2SRifFqnixeAueq9Q%3D%7Ctkp%3ABFBM_q2OwZFi",
      "condition":"Pre-Owned",
      "price":{
         "raw":"$13.50",
         "extracted":13.5
      },
      "shipping":"Free shipping",
      "top_rated":true,
      "returns":"Free returns",
      "quantity_sold":"199 sold",
      "extracted_quantity_sold":199,
      "thumbnail":"https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/q8AAAOSwJUhiC2jb/s-l300.jpg",
      "seller":{
         "username":"jorgetcg",
         "reviews":714,
         "positive_feedback_in_percentage":99.7
      },
      "stock_status":"Last one"
   }
   ... and other results
]
```

You can see more use cases (with examples) in their documentation.

> Disclaimer: I'm author of this package